# Command Python2 not found

Tags: python, windows, command-line, path, version

I have to use `Python2` for the following command: `python2 -m pip install SomePackage` in the command line. I get the message that `Python2`is not found, but I have definitly installed Python 2.7.1.

When I run `python --version` I get the output `Python 3.5.1`.

Edit:
I use Windows. And the commands `whereis` and `env` were also not found.

Comment: and what do you get when you run `python2 --version`?

Comment: ​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​What's the system you're using? Did you try `pip2 install SomePackage`? Also, try `whereis python2` and `env python2`?

Comment: @M.T I already wrote: Python2 is not found.

Comment: @Kevin I use Windows

Comment: @kame That means there is no python2 command in your path variable. Add the pyhton2 path to your Path variable in windows. This should fix the problem

Comment: @Kevin whereis and env were also not found. :/

Comment: @kame: ​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​Well, these are Linux commands...However, where did you install Python? Try run Python from there? And as ZeusNet said, check out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3701646/how-to-add-to-the-pythonpath-in-windows-7).

Comment: I added the missing C:\Python2.7 to my Path, but I still can't run pip2 or python2. pip3 is working, but I need pip2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Under windows you have to use:

```
py -2 yourfilename  // for python2.x
py -3 yourfilename  // for python3.x
```

Answer (score 1):

If you really have installed python2.x and it is on your `path`, you can ensure that you are installing for python2 by running

```
pip2 install somepackage
```

Equivalently you can run

```
pip3 install somepackage
```

to ensure that it is installed on python3.x.

This can become a bit messy/tedious in the long run, so it might be worth looking into using virtual environments, or something like [miniconda](http://conda.pydata.org/miniconda.html) which tend to handle this quite well.

Comment: I installed python2.7. I have it in my path but pip2 is still not running.

Comment: @kame I assume you have installed pip on python2? If not check out [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12476379/5422525)

Answer (score 0):

The canonical way to find out where a command is found on the path with with the Bourne shell built-in,

```
$ command -v python
/usr/local/anaconda/bin/python
```

(BTW, don't use **which**; let the shell tell you what it's doing.)

It could easily be that Python2 is on your path, but later in the list than the one that's being found.  It could also be that the shell's cache of found executables needs updating:

```
$ help hash
hash: hash [-lr] [-p pathname] [-dt] [name ...]
Remember or display program locations.
...
  -d                forget the remembered location of each NAME

$ hash -d python; command -v python
/usr/local/anaconda/bin/python
```

To display the path in a more friendly way:

```
$ echo $PATH | tr :  \\n 
/usr/local/anaconda/bin
/usr/local/sbin
/usr/local/bin
/usr/sbin
/usr/bin
/sbin
/bin
/usr/games
/usr/local/games
```

You may want to re-arrange your path.  Another trick I sometimes use is to rename the system-provided executable, perhaps by capitalizing it, so it's still available but won't be found without special effort.