# "-bash: python2: command not found" on OS X

Tags: python, bash, macos

I'm trying to use [this](https://github.com/Tamriel/quod_libet_import_itunes_ratings) script to import my iTunes library to another program.

At the step where I enter `python2 export_to_quod_libet.py`, I'm getting an error message that says that the `python2` command can't be found. I figured out through `python -v` that I definitely have Python 2.7 installed, so I'm really confused about this.

I did find a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37411607/command-python2-not-found) being asked here, but the original poster was using Windows (whereas I'm using OS X El Capitan), so a lot of what was said at least didn't *seem* applicable to my situation.

Could someone tell me what I'm doing wrong, please?

Comment: Just use `python export_to_quod_libet.py`.

Comment: If you can call `python -v` just use `python export_to_quod_libet.py` instead of `python2 ...`.

Comment: `python2` is just a filename, so it needs to match the name of an available program in your PATH. Fix your script by editing it to use the name available in your system, as the previous comments suggested.

Comment: Okay, yeah, this was probably a dumb question. Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 14):

Maybe you could try do define an alias. It seems that python2 is hardcoded somewhere in the script.

You could try (just an example):

```
alias python2="python2.7"
```

and then run the script -- hope that helps.

Kind regards,
  Julian

Comment: This was a good suggestion for me, as I prefer to use a `pyenv` installed version rather than system python

Answer (score 4):

I confirmed it works on macOS. I installed Python 2.7 and 3.5 using brew commands:

```
brew update
brew install python
brew install python3
```